# Can I check in a golfing size umbrella as my 3rd check in luggage?

Tags: luggage, qatar-airways

I am flying from the US in May and I have a golfing size umbrella as a souvenir which I want to bring back but I already have 2 luggages and can't bring the umbrella as a carry on for safety reasons. Will they allow it be checked it in?

Answer (score 4):

The size should be ok. It might end up as an oversize luggage which means that you'll potentially have to pay extra money for it.

Then with Qatar Airways, you have the right to check in 2 pieces in First and Business class and one piece in Economy.

Details here :
http://www.qatarairways.com/us/en/baggage.page

You can also purchase additional baggage allowance. This way, you can check in your umbrella in addition to 1 or 2 pieces already included have by default.

Comment: Note that an extra piece for the flight from the US will run you [$200](http://www.qatarairways.com/us/en/excess-baggage-rates.page) if purchased online. It would have to be a pretty nice umbrella to be worthwhile, and if the umbrella is really that valuable to you, I'd want to pack it in something to keep it safe before attempting to check it.

Comment: It's not worth $200 dollars. I will see what I can do. If I am checking it in I will pack it well.

Answer (score 4):

[Golf umbrellas are allowed as carry-on for flights from the US.](https://apps.tsa.dhs.gov/mytsa/cib_results.aspx?search=golf%20umbrella)

It is likely that the airline would refuse to carry such an item as checked baggage due to the chances of it getting lost/damaged in the baggage handling system at the airport.